# How to set apache nifi process proprieties via rest call or by a program

Tags: rest, apache-nifi

I have defined a NIFI flow to read the data from kafka and write in to mongodb. I exported this as a Nifi flow template, now I need to set topic name and collections pragmatically and start the process. 
Also need to start such nifi process flows for different kafka topics

Is this possible   to set the properties and call start Nifi process using any rest call or is there any spring-boot integration ?

Comment: everything you could do in nifi web UI covered with api. http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Comment: I want throw the API but I did not see any api to do below . Take a template create a flow, get a process ID and set the properties then start the process .

Comment: Take the browser, press f12 (dev tools), switch to the network tab, do everything you need with nifi through browser, reproduce all calls in your code.